# JSF: conditionally render a list item (<li>)

Tags: java, jsf, rendering

I just inherited a project implemented in JSF. I have the following code which looks fine in Chrome, but Firefox renders the borders on the "empty" list items:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/home">Home</li>
    <li>
        <s:link view="/signup.xhtml" rendered="#{someCondition}">Sign Up</s:link>
    </li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>
```

Which ends up looking like:

[image]

Is there a JSF tag to conditionally render the `<li>` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No `li` is vanilla html, not a jsf component.

You can *hack* it by putting a `<h:panelGroup />` around the `li` element and setting the `rendered` property on it.

ie.

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{someCondition}">
   <li>
      <s:link view="/signup.xhtml">Sign Up</s:link>
   </li>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

Another option is to use `<f:verbatim rendered="#{someCondition}" >`, but keep in mind that it has been deprecated in JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 28):

If you do it as in @CoolBeans example, you will get a <span> around your <li>. In some cases it might disrupt your layout, besides you don't really want an extra tag under <ul>. To get rid of it, use `<ui:fragment rendered="#{condition}" />` around your item instead of <h:panelGroup>.

Also you can use style attribute to hide an item:

```
<li style="display: #{condition ? 'list-item' : 'none'};" />
```

Comment: I'm using jsf 1.2 and don't get an extra span on render. [The docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/panelGroup.html) you only get a div or span if you specify style, styleClass or layout attributes.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use the core JSTL library:

```
<c:if test="#{someCondition}">
    <li>
        <s:link view="/signup.xhtml">Sign Up</s:link>
    </li>
</c:if>
```

I think using this core tag makes the code easier to understand than using the panelGroup tag.